# What are databricks spark delta tables? Does they also stores data for a specific session and how can I view these delta tables and their structure

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

What is the purpose of spark delta tables? Does they meant to store data permanently or only holds the processing data till the session lasts. How can I view them in spark cluster and what database they belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the purpose of spark delta tables?

The primary goal is to enable single table transnational writes in multicluster setups. This is achieved by keeping a transaction log (idea very similar to append-only tables in typical database systems).

> Does they meant to store data permanently or only holds the processing data till the session lasts.

There are persistent, and by definition scoped across the sessions.

> . How can I view them in spark cluster and what database

Same as any other table in Spark. There are not specific to any database, and written using `delta` format.

Comment: So you mentioned "they're persistent, and by definition scoped across the sessions", can you please explain it little further. So what I want to know is e.g. someone has setup some delta tables, and If I try to access those delta tables from my own cluster, they're not displaying any of the data. So do I need to run the whole transformation again and need to load the data into delta tables? And does loading the data again, can cause any impact ?